# Using the Hash::make method to update all entries in table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Since I'm porting an app to Laravel and it's using the Auth Class, I need to change all the passwords in my users table to bycrypt (using `Hash::make()`).

The thing is that I want to use the usernames as default password (so when the migration is done, my user "Mario" will have a Password of "Mario") — I wanna do this with all the entries of the database via a Migration, but I can't seem to make it, since I don't know how to get the value of the select, hash it, then use it in the update.

Is there any way to do this *without using loops*? (i.e without making one query per user)

**EDIT:** Yes, this is impossible to do without loops. I realized that. And @Adrenaxus has the right answer.

Comment: Do you _have to_ use migrations? Otherwise you could just loop through every user in a `foreach()` and set the new password, or am I missing something? Why don't you want to use loops, I don't see any other way...

Comment: @Adrenaxus Oh, I didn't thought of that. A 1 time thing, you say? (when logging in the 1st time?) — I don't want to use loops because there are lots of users. And, in the case there are thousands (hypothetical), doing thousands and thousands of queries can kill the database, right? Not so efficient (knowing there's a way to do that with 1 query)

Comment: yeah, that's the deal :) check out the code in my answer...

Comment: Don't worry about the number of users, sql is designed for large amounts of querys (unless you have one trillion users). Besides that, you can only use `Hash::make()` in laravel PHP, how would you accomplish that in an SQL query?

Comment: When I was writing my response, I thought exactly the same: I would need a `bycrypt()` function in MySQL so that would work... so yes, my question was outrageous and outright stupid, and you had the answer that I had, too (but with a better syntax =)

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and remember: There's no stupid questions, only stupid answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
foreach(User::all() as $user){
    $user->password = Hash::make($user->username);
    $user->save();
}
```